# Openmp linked list

Tags: c++, graph, parallel-processing, linked-list, openmp

I tried to parallelize the linked list using the openmp task but instead of getting speed up  it goes much more slowly. Could be due to the fact that the list is very long and I pay the generation of many tasks. How can I do to have a speed up?

Code: https://dpaste.de/ZbKS

Comment: Please provide some code sample. Parallelizing a linked list is not trivial, you can have races on updates.

Comment: If you're trying to traverse a simple linked list, it's impossible to do so in parallel, since you can't discover the `n`th node without already having visited the `(n-1)`th node. You may wish to consider a different data structure.